# vertical alignment of two columns in a beamer frame

Tags: beamer, two-column, minipage

I'm trying present two concepts side by side in a frame. And I want each lineitem to be vertically aligned. Here is is an example where they are not aligned.

```
\begin{frame}{An Example of using columns in beamer}

\begin{columns}

\begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
\color{red}\rule{\linewidth}{4pt}
foo
\begin{itemize}
\item this is line 1 of foo
\item this is line 2 of foo which is long
\item this is line 3 of foo
\end{itemize}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
\color{blue}\rule{\linewidth}{4pt}
bar
\begin{itemize}
\item this is line 1 of bar
\item this is line 2 of bar
\item need this line to be aligned with line 3 of foo
\end{itemize}
\end{column}

\end{columns}

\end{frame}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is to add some phantom text in both columns so that each bullet points "takes" up the same number of lines:

[image]

### Notes:

- Also added `[t]` to align the columns at the top

### Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{An Example of using columns in beamer}

\begin{columns}

\begin{column}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
\color{red}\rule{\linewidth}{4pt}
foo
\begin{itemize}
\item this is line 1 of foo
\item this is line 2 of foo which is long
\item this is line 3 of foo 
\end{itemize}
\end{column}

\begin{column}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
\color{blue}\rule{\linewidth}{4pt}
bar
\begin{itemize}
\item this is line 1 of bar
\item this is line 2 of bar \phantom{which is long}
\item need this line to be aligned with line 3 of foo
\end{itemize}
\end{column}

\end{columns}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked!! But I feel this is not an elegant way to do it. Very often, people try to compare and contrast two things in a frame and there should be a easy way to do it.

Comment: @arunmoezhi: Have modified solution since I first posted it, so slightly simpler, but still involves `\phantom{}` spacing (but only one one of the `\item`s). I am not much of a `beamer` expert so perhaps there is a more elegant way in `beamer`. I do know of other more complicated ways in case you do this very often which would involve packaging a similar process into a macro, but I think using `\phantom{}` is a common way to tweak things.

Comment: I'm fine with this simple tweak using `\phantom{}`. But I just thought someone else might need this feature frequently.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a solution via two new commands : `\parallelcontent` and `\parallelitem`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand\parallelcontent[2]{
  \begin{columns}[t]
    \column{0.48\textwidth} #1
    \column{0.48\textwidth} #2
  \end{columns}
}
\newcommand\parallelitem[2]{
  \parallelcontent
  {\begin{itemize} \item #1 \end{itemize}}
  {\begin{itemize} \item #2 \end{itemize}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{An Example of using columns in beamer}

  \parallelcontent
  {\textcolor{red}{\rule{\linewidth}{4pt} foo}}
  {\textcolor{blue}{\rule{\linewidth}{4pt} bar}}
  \parallelitem
  {this is line 1 of foo}
  {this is line 1 of bar}
  \parallelitem
  {this is line 2 of foo which is long}
  {this is line 2 of bar}
  \parallelitem
  {this is line 3 of foo}
  {need this line to be aligned with line 3 of foo}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if there's a different number of items in the two lists? I mean, in the question the reason for misalignment is due to the different lenght of the texts in the two items of a couple. Another reason could be that one of the two lists has some missing item.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis In this case, you may use `\parallelcontent` with an empty part (for the missing part)...

Comment: Do you mean using `\parallelcontent` insted of `\parallelitem`, and manually insert `itemize` environment in one of the two arguments of `\parallelcontent`?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Exactly.